# Transferring Data from SQL Server to SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

How do I transfer a database from a physical server running SQL Server 2012 to another server running SQL Server 2008 Express? The database was created by `sa` under SQL Server 2012.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from upgrading SQL Server 2008 Express to SQL Server 2014 Express, or installing the new version alongside 2008? It's free after all...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I transfer a database from a physical server running SQL Server 2012 to another server running SQLEXPRESS 2008

Direct transfer of database using backup restore or using attach dettach is not possible because you cannot move database from higher version(SS 2012) to lower version(SS2008). Its not allowed by Microsoft.

What you can do is script out the objects manually run the script in destination database and then use import export wizard to move data. [This link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/) would help

Moreover SQL Server 2008 express database has limitation of 4 G database. So when you move data using Imp exp wizard make sure you do not exceed the limit.

PS: If you would have searched the net you could have found lot of similar threads on how to achieve this.

Comment: There are also numerous other compatibility issues to be addressed, unless the DB was created on 2012 at an appropriate compatibility level.

Comment: As an aside, if you are trying to go to express 2008R2, the database size limit is 10GB.

Comment: @Pieter and even at compatibility level = 100, this doesn't stop you from using things in 2012 that will break on 2008 (code that will stop working, or objects that just won't transfer).